# Como salvar um dado com mongose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber como salvo um dado no mongodb, pois eu tentei um método e deu certo, agora estou tentando o mesmo em outra função e não está dando certo.

Obrigado pela ajuda

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: salvar é inserir novo registro ou atualizar outro registro?

Comment: Inclua o código no corpo da pergunta e não em um print para facilitar a pesquisa.

Answer (score 0):

o metodo .lean() após o .findOne() não lhe permite usar o .save() e também  você tem uma virgula após o nome

```
categorias.nome = req.body.nome,
```

acredito que após estas modificações seu código irá funcionar

Comment: Muito Obrigado, isso resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar os metodo findOneAndUpdate() ou findByIdAndUpdate() para buscar um campo e altera-lo

`const categoria = {name: req.body.name, ...}`

`categorias.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id}, categoria )`

Mais em : [mongoose queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.